# How to remove OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationConverter for token endpoint in Spring Authorization Server?

Tags: spring-authorization-server

I'm trying to use Spring Authorization Server - let's call it 'SAS' (based on Spring Boot 3.1.5) as a fake authorization server that would be used instead of real authorization server that our application uses - for integration tests or Selenium tests - so the test environment doesn't have to have access to the real authorization server.

I can configure the client app to make a direct request to SAS to /oauth2/token endpoint and I would like SAS to return an access token - so the client sends its clientId and clientSecret - and SAS returns a token.

The problem: the POST request from the client doesn't have the "code" attribute. Because of that the request in rejected by SAS in `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationConverter.convert()` in lines:

```
Authentication clientPrincipal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters = OAuth2EndpointUtils.getParameters(request);
String code = (String)parameters.getFirst("code");
if (!StringUtils.hasText(code) || ((List)parameters.get("code")).size() != 1) {
                OAuth2EndpointUtils.throwError("invalid_request", "code", 
"https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-5.2");
            }
```

My server configuration:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

        var authorizationServerConfigurer = http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class);
        authorizationServerConfigurer.oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());

        authorizationServerConfigurer.tokenEndpoint(tokenEndpoint ->
                tokenEndpoint
                        .accessTokenRequestConverters(new AuthenticationConverterConsumer())
                        .accessTokenRequestConverter(
                          new CustomOAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationConverter())
        );

        return http.build();
    }
```

I can add my own `CustomOAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationConverter` (I'm intentionally omitting AuthenticationConverterConsumer details which is irrelevant here) to the existing list of default converters but I don't know if it is possible to also remove the `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationConverter` so the token request is not rejected by this class.

During SAS startup the `OAuth2TokenEndpointConfigurer.configure()` is called which calls

```
OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter tokenEndpointFilter = new OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter(authenticationManager, authorizationServerSettings.getTokenEndpoint());
List<AuthenticationConverter> authenticationConverters = createDefaultAuthenticationConverters();
if (!this.accessTokenRequestConverters.isEmpty()) {
            authenticationConverters.addAll(0, this.accessTokenRequestConverters);
}
```

and `OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter` constructor simply calls

```
this.authenticationConverter = new DelegatingAuthenticationConverter(Arrays.asList(
    new OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationConverter(), 
    new OAuth2RefreshTokenAuthenticationConverter(), 
    new OAuth2ClientCredentialsAuthenticationConverter(), 
    new OAuth2DeviceCodeAuthenticationConverter()));
```

so the list of converters in hardcoded and includes `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationConverter`.

**Question**: is it possible to configure tokenEndpoint so it doesn't use `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationConverter` ?

P.S. I know that what I'm trying to do is probably against OAuth2 specification. I just need to know if it is somehow possible to tweak the SAS to allow it.

Thank you in advance for any hints.

I also tried with AuthenticationConverterConsumer whit the following implementation:

```
public class AuthenticationConverterConsumer implements Consumer<List<AuthenticationConverter>> {
    List<AuthenticationConverter> converters = new ArrayList<>(10);
    @Override
    public void accept(List<AuthenticationConverter> authenticationConverters) {
        /*
        0 = {CustomOAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationConverter@7242}
        1 = {OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationConverter@7237}
        2 = {OAuth2RefreshTokenAuthenticationConverter@7243}
        3 = {OAuth2ClientCredentialsAuthenticationConverter@7244}
        4 = {OAuth2DeviceCodeAuthenticationConverter@7245}
         */

        Iterator<AuthenticationConverter> iterator = authenticationConverters.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            AuthenticationConverter converter = iterator.next();
            if(converter instanceof OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationConverter) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }

        converters.addAll(authenticationConverters);
    }
}
```

but the OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationConverter is still available and rejects the requests because of the missing "code" attribute.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-oauth-testing-access-control

Comment: That article focuses on writing the tests with mocked identity/authorization. By I need to be able to start my application also in normal mode (not as a spring test) - but instead of using real authentication server it would use my fake-authorization server.

Comment: if the authorization server is not "real", then token validation on resource server(s) will fail. Use a "normal" authorization server (in a test container or a local instance) to start your application in "normal" mode.

Comment: What is the `grant_type` parameter value in the request to the /oauth2/token endpoint?  If `grant_type=authorization_code`, then the [OAuth 2.0 specification](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/authorization-code-request/) requires the `code` parameter is also present in the request.

Comment: The grant_type=authorization_code.

Anyway I solved the problem by writing my own server and mocking the token endpoint and userinfo endpoint and adapt the responses to what the client expects. Because of that the question could be closed.

If someone still knows how to adjust the Spring Authorization Server by removing OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationConverter from request processing I would be grateful for any answer. I'm just still curious if it is possible.